# If we share a file or folder using anyone link, then will any user who have the link will be able to see the file, or only the users who got the link

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, external-sharing

We have the following requirement:-

1. we have uploaded some videos and files
2. we want to share these videos and files with external users >> where the users can access the videos and file without requiring them to login or to register as guest accounts.

so i found that inside the sharing policy we can achieve this by changing the sharing level to the most permissive as follow:-

[image]

but i have the following question/concern:- let say we generate anyone link and we share it to userA & userB >> then will anyone who have access to the internet and has the file link be able to see the files and videos? or the anyone link will only work for the users who receive the anyone files links?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**“Anyone Sharing  Link” is also known as “Anonymous Link”**

Using "**Anyone Shareing link**" that let **anyone** who has the link access the files or folders **without authenticating**.

Answer (score 1):

The Anyone option means anyone who has the link can access the file:

> Allow users to share files and folders by using links that let anyone who has the link access the files or folders without authenticating. This setting also allows users to share sites with new and existing guests who authenticate. If you select this setting, you can restrict the Anyone links so that they must expire within a specific number of days, or so that they can give only View permission.

[Manage sharing settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off#which-option-to-select)

[Best practices for sharing files and folders with unauthenticated users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/best-practices-anonymous-sharing?view=o365-worldwide)